# uploadify | changing uploadifysettings on the fly

Tags: jquery, amazon-s3, uploadify

I am stuck.  I am using uploadify to upload multiple files to my s3 server.  I would like to put **each file into a folder that has a unique identifier**.  What I was hoping to do was to use this syntax to accomplish that  (note uuid is a jquery plugin to generate uuids):

```
'onComplete'  : function(event,queueId,fileObj,response) {
   $('#fileInput').uploadifySettings('folder',$.uuid())
}
```

My issue is that when this callback gets called -- i not longer have access to `$('#fileInput').uploadifySettings(x,y)`  i get that it is an undefined method ?!

Other uploadify settings of note:

```
'auto':  'true'
'multi': 'true'
```

and I am uploading directly to Amazon s3

Has anyone run into this?  Ideas on how to solve?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem now. The call to uploadifySettings crashes my script.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this same problem as follows, by changing the scriptData "onSelect" so when you select a new file:

```
onSelect : function(){
            $('#images_upload_file').uploadifySettings("scriptData", {'yourvar': yourvalue });
        },
```

that seems to do the trick

Comment: Thanks.  This does not work for me.  Question, in your settings are you using auto:true and/or multi:true ?  I wonder if those are the culprits.  And if so -- is there a work around -- multi upload is a requirement for me

Comment: ^^ following up -- did this work for you with auto and multi set to true?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm not completely misunderstanding your question.

Wouldn't it be very easy to do that on the server-side? You have to handle the upload on the server-side anyway, which usually involves in some way to fetch the uploaded file from a temporary location, make sure it's not evil, and then to copy it to its final resting place.

At that last copying step, you could easily introduce a uuid (in this case generated on the server side as well, I suppose).

Would that be a valid approach, or am I missing a requirement you have?

Comment: Thanks for chiming in.  I am actually uploading the files directly to Amazon s3, and while I could use callbacks to my server to move the file upon loading, it certainly would be easier to put them in right place to start.  But -- only if it is possible!

Comment: @Jonathan: Ah, that's why you want to do it that way. I would still think it's possible to do it the way you've described, but it might require changing uploadify's innards, unless there's an event/option I have overlooked so far. I'm not sure if they would frown upon that. I won't be able to investigate further until tomorrow myself, but I'm curious to figure it out now. ;)

Comment: Cool -- would love any insight -- I am not a javascript expert.  Its weird how uploadifySettings behaves during its events.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After hours of pain I finally solved it by manually manipulating the flashvars string that is passed to the flash upload object.

Given this HTML element:

```
<div id="file_upload" name="file_upload"></div>
```

I proceed to initiate uploadify on that element with this:

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
    // Empty folder path
    'folder'    : ''
});
```

This adds an `<object>` element with several `<param>` children to your HTML-file. One of these `<param>` elements is named "flashvars", and its string value contain the upload folder path. So, in order to change the folder-value, I search that string for the "folder=" argument like so:

```
// Find correct <param> element and retrieve it's value
var found = $("#file_uploadUploader").find("param[name=flashvars]").val();

// Search within that value for the specific folder argument using a regex
// and replace find with new_path
found = found.replace(/folder\=.*\/&/, "folder="+new_path+"&");
```

Hope this helps.